# [SymmetricDS]: Transform using PK insert duplicate data

Tags: symmetricds

I have a table physical PK is ID (identity) at both sides. During sync, I manually add transform column to

ID - remove, pk: 0

Num - copy, pk: 1

DateTime - copy, pk: 1

I think Num and DateTime would serve as virtual PK for symmetric to find which row to update/delete. My transform have UpdateFirst = 1

But in my target table, I get 2 record with same Num and DateTime (ID is different).

This only  happen to one of my table, other tables with same setting are working fine. I just like to know how it can happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform_column.pk` to set that `Num` and `DateTime` are the composed primary key at the destination. This should signal symmetricDs not to duplicate rows but to update the ones having the same `(Num, DateTime)` values.

Comment: I also think the same, but in fact it has duplicate row. And no way to trace back where gone wrong.